# Rails console Permission denied @ rb_sysopen Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

When I exit rails console, terminal creates this error.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:37:in `initialize': 
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/.irbrc_history (Errno::EACCES)
```

At first I don't care about this error message, but soon I realized that my active record update in rails console was not applied.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem. ***edit/create*** `~/.irbrc`

```
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 10000
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-history"
```

Comment: I have added the file name `~/.irbrc`

Comment: Oh... got it. You are my lifesaver. Thanks!