# Rails console access gets Permission denied @ rb_sysopen Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I try to access rails console with rails c,  terminal gives me this error
`: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/yannherveeaniman/.irb_history (Errno::EACCES)`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you try `sudo rails c`?

Comment: still not working, I get ```https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first. ``` Bundle install does not solve the problem either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Looks like permission issue. I found 2 solutions. I hope one of them will solve your issue.

1. Looking at the error it seems like it is unable to access. We can try to give access by below command

   `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/yannherveeaniman/.irb_history` (giving all access to file)

   OR

   `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/yannherveeaniman` (giving all access to your folder)
2. **create/edit** `~/.irbrc`

   ```
    require 'irb/ext/save-history'
    IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 10000
    IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-history"
   ```

   credits - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52360668/18073270

Thank You for reaching out to this beautiful platform. Hopefully your issues will be resolved.

Regards.

Comment: @YannHervee Glad you found it helpful, could you please approve the answer?

Answer (score 1):

### 'write': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - tmp/sockets/puma.state (Errno::EACCES)

I faced a similar issue due to a gem called puma. whenever I run "rails s" to start rails server I got
**'write': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - tmp/sockets/puma.state (Errno::EACCES)**
so the solution was pretty forward first of all i checked the permissions for the file causing issue 'tmp/sockets/puma.rb'

```
ls -la ./tmp/sockets/
->: -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     78 فروری  23 15:13 puma.state
```

so it had a write permission at user level.
if not try to assign it write permission but only at user level.

Then I try to change ownership to current user.

```
sudo chown $(whoami) ./tmp/sockets/puma.state
```

and that was my hack.

Before trying this make sure a few things.

- rvm is installed and configures correctly.
- Only one version of bundler is installed.
- Make sure to install gems by not using sudo that will install the
  gems at system level ruby.
- Make sure to run 'rvm use (ruby version you using)' although rvm
  picks automatically ruby version from .ruby-version file. But make
  sure that you are using correct current ruby version by running 'ruby -v'.